# Resize tiff image in Python

Tags: python, image, tiff, python-imaging-library

Tried resize my image (weight > 100 MB) using:

```
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> image = Image.open(path_to_the_file)
>>> new_image = image.resize((200, 200))
```

and received ValueError: tile cannot extend outside image.

The size of original image is

```
>>> image.size
>>> (4922, 3707)
```

The same error I received while doing thumbnails, rotate etc.

What I am doing wrong?

Edit:
Checked image using ImageMagic:

```
$ identify file.tif
file.tif[0] TIFF 4922x3707 4922x3707+0+0 32-bit Grayscale Gray 31.23MB   0.000u 0:00.009
file.tif[1] TIFF 2461x1854 2461x1854+0+0 32-bit Grayscale Gray 31.23MB 0.000u 0:00.000
filetif[2] TIFF 1231x927 1231x927+0+0 32-bit Grayscale Gray 31.23MB 0.000u 0:00.000
file.tif[3] TIFF 616x464 616x464+0+0 32-bit Grayscale Gray 31.23MB 0.000u 0:00.000
file.tif[4] TIFF 308x232 308x232+0+0 32-bit Grayscale Gray 31.23MB 0.000u 0:00.000
file.tif[5] TIFF 154x116 154x116+0+0 32-bit Grayscale Gray 31.23MB 0.000u 0:00.000
identify: Unknown field with tag 33550 (0x830e) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory' @ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/881.
identify: Unknown field with tag 33922 (0x8482) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory' @ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/881.
identify: Unknown field with tag 34735 (0x87af) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory' @ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/881.
identify: Unknown field with tag 34736 (0x87b0) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory' @ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/881.
```

Comment: Is your TIFF image a single frame? Also, you could try using `image.thumbnail((200, 200), Image.ANTIALIAS)`

Comment: @MartinEvans `Image.ANTIALIAS` doesn't seem to be a listed re-sampling option for `Image.thumbnail()`. It's been renamed to `Image.LANCZOS` since PIL version 2.7.0

Comment: The TIFF image is in single band. The mode is Float32

Comment: ".. while doing thumbnails, rotate etc." – so, can you do *anything at all* with your image? If not, then PIL may not support it properly.

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be here, from the [docs](http://www.effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm):

> Note that the bilinear and bicubic filters in the current version of PIL are **not well-suited for large downsampling ratios (e.g. when creating thumbnails)**. You should use ANTIALIAS unless speed is much more important than quality.

In this case, add at your code `Image.ANTIALIAS`

```
from PIL import Image
image = Image.open(path_to_the_file)
new_image = image.resize((200, 200) Image.ANTIALIAS)
```

Should now do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I was using `ggdalwarp` like this :

```
gdal.Warp('output.tiff', 'input.tiff', xRes=0.5, yRes=0.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should install pytho-resize-image package.

One example

```
from PIL import Image

from resizeimage import resizeimage


with open('acajeb-image.jpeg', 'r+b') as f:
    with Image.open(f) as image:
        cover = resizeimage.resize_cover(image, [200, 200])
        cover.save('test-image-cover.jpeg', image.format)
```

You can install package with

```
pip install python-resize-image
```

Comment: This is not what op asked for.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `Image.ANTIALIAS` parameter:

```
new_image = image.resize((200, 200), Image.ANTIALIAS)
```

This worked for me in one of my previous projects.